# Windows Phone, garbage collector don't clean view even with only weak references

Tags: c#, memory, garbage-collection, windows-phone

I have a WP7 app that has a memory leak caused by a view, after spending a entire day cleaning it up I finally ended up with only weak references to the view instance.
The problem is that the garbage collector still doesn't clean the view (I added some code on the destructor to check it out), causing the app inevitably to crash (with out of memory exception), after some aggressive testing.

The screenshot of the GC Roots:
http://1drv.ms/1g488IO

Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that even if the image shows that the root is weak, it actually doesn't mean it is. To solve this issue I just removed all the gc roots, and by doing that the view was destructed.